# Complex jquery selector loop function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, addclass

I need to find in a list and list item with a particular ID, the `<a>` with an href equal to a variable `<li>`  (and then add a particular class to it).

```
<ul id="elementSelectionList">
   <li><a href="#bzm_tagline" class="text">Tagline</a></li>
</ul>

<input id="form_tagline" name="tagline" value="">
```

.

```
 $('#fields input').each(function (){
        var elementListing = this.id.replace('form', 'bzm');

        if( !$(this).val() ) {
            $('#elementSelectionList li a[href*="#' + elementListing + '"]')
                .hasClass('text')
                .removeClass('filled')
                .addClass('empty');
        } 
 });
```

I'm getting the error: object false has no method 'removeClass'.
Want to know how I can acheive what I'm trying to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JS is slightly incorrect. Here goes what looks to be better:

```
$('#fields input').each(function (){
       var elementListing = this.id.replace('form', 'bzm');
       var element = $('#elementSelectionList li a[href="#' + elementListing + '"]');

       if( !$(this).val() && element.hasClass('text') ) {
           element
               .removeClass('filled')
               .addClass('empty');
       } 
});
```

`hasClass`, naturally, returns `boolean`, not a `jQuery object`

Comment: thanks. the chains of jquery selectors often seem to me to implicitly have if statements within, but I guess I took it too far that time.

Answer (score 1):

I think the elementSelectionList selection should be:

```
$('#elementSelectionList li a[href*="#' + elementListing + '"]')
```

E.g. it should start with a '#'. Also, make sure that the javascript is defined after the `#fields` div/form (?), if you included it in `<script>` tags.

Comment: you're right! still not working, though.. I wonder if my use of 'hasClass' is correct..

Answer (score 1):

The [`.hasClass` method](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) returns a Boolean and is thus **not available for chaining**.

Since what you seem to be doing is `.removeClass('filled').addClass('empty')` on elements *with* the `.text` class, you might as well just add this to the selector:

```
$('#fields input').each(function (){
    var elementListing = this.id.replace('form', 'bzm');

    if( !$(this).val() ) {
        $('#elementSelectionList li a.text[href*="#' + elementListing + '"]') // Added .text here!
            .removeClass('filled')
            .addClass('empty');
    } 
});
```

Comment: i actually wanted to do something like `.hasClass('.text, .logo')` as mentioned in the comments on the jquery docs, but it doesn't work